# Subgroup generated by Sylow $q$-groups of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $\mathfrak{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers and $n$ the order of $G$. Since $n>0$, there exists a unique family $(\nu_q(n))_{q\in\mathfrak{P}}$ of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n=\prod_{q\in\mathfrak{P}}q^{\nu_q(n)},$$
where the set $\mathfrak{Q}:=\{q\in\mathfrak{P}\ |\ \nu_q(n)\ne0\}$ is finite.

It is clear that, for all $q\in\mathfrak{Q}$, we have $n\in q\mathbb{Z}$. For each $q\in\mathfrak{Q}$, let $P_q$ denote a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. Finally, let
$$H:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{y\ |\ (\exists)(x\in\left(\bigcup_{q\in\mathfrak{Q}} P_q\right)^{[1,n]}\land y=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i) \right\}.$$

Obviously $H\leq G$.

I want to show that $G=H$. My idea is to show that $\text{ord}(G)=\text{ord}(H)$. But I am not sure how to calculate the cardinality of $H$ since it is a generated subgroup.

Comment: Firstly, $P_q$ is a group so $P_q = P_q^{-1}$. Secondly, a group can have more than one Sylow $q$-subgroup, so you cannot say "the Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$".  The result that you are trying to prove follows from the fact that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$  and its order is divisible by $q^{\nu_q(n)}$ for all primes $q$.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I am not sure that I understand why your last sentence holds: i.e. I am not sure why $|H|$ is divisible by $q^{\nu_q(n)}$ for each prime $q$.

Comment: Should I use Lagrange? Edit: Yes, Lagrange sanctions the conclusion.